# Is it a good practice to force developer to comply with a protocol in objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I am developing a simple set of reusable code. I have created a protocol to group a set of methods and ask the user at run time for data.

I think that setting a delegate would be mandatory. Can I force the developer at runtime to set the delegate by throwing an assert stating the reason?

Is this a good practice to enforce the user of my classes by using asserts? Does it have a design level flaw?

Comment: a nice read: http://mattgemmell.com/2012/05/24/api-design/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First the "good practice" question:

- Don't make methods required unless they actually are.
- Don't make methods optional if they aren't.
- Not a critical one, more of an opinion

  - Provide a method `initWithDelegate:` if a delegate is **required**
  - I often come across data structures where I don't know that there is a delegate pattern until I investigate. With the specific `init` method, I'm made aware of it earlier.

You can cause warnings at compile time by simply adding the `@required` indicator to your protocol:

```
@protocol SuperAwesomeProtocol <NSObject>

@required
-(void) requiredMethod1;
-(void) requiredMethod2;

@optional
-(void) optionalMethod1;
-(void) optionalMethod2;

@end

//and making your delegate specific:
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SuperAwesomeProtocol> delegate;
```

You can still cause runtime asserts with:

```
if (!delegate || ![delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requiredMethod1)])
{
    //Assertion failure
}
```

Comment: I was aware of using @required. But my case has all the methods as optional.

Comment: Nice answer. I would say: just implement `initWithDelegate:` if the delegate is really needed. For example [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a delegate but you don't really need it unless you are doing advanced stuff. And if you are doing advanced stuff then you probably will be used to *at least* take a glance at headers/documentation :)

Comment: Don't use an assertion.  Just provide initWithDelegate: as the designated initialiser (returning nil if a nil delegate is passed) and be done with it.  Asserts are just a bad idea generally.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think it is good practice to use protocol in the application..

Protocols declare methods that can be implemented by any class.

Below are the situation in which use of protocol is good.

1. To declare methods that others are expected to implement
2. To declare the interface to an object while concealing its class
3. To capture similarities among classes that are not hierarchically
   related

Comment: My question is not towards using protocols but towards enforcing user of my classes (developer ) to provide the delegate by using asserts if   user does not provide the delegate.